# jQuery ajax() saying parseerror while json passes jsonlint

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I have a simple website with jQuery (1.8.2) doing an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:1337?callback=?',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(a,b,c) {
    console.log('success',a,b,c);
  },
  error: function(a,b,c) {
    console.log('error',a,b,c);
  }
});
```

The webpage has the headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers *
```

the ajax being return'd is:

```
[{"a":"b"}]
```

(which also passes JSONlint), The json is being served as `application/json`

However I get a parse error:

```
'error'
[object]
'parsererror'
Error
  arguments: undefined
  get stack: function () { [native code] }
  message: "jQuery18209882410678546876_1355861965752 was not called"
  set stack: function () { [native code] }
  type: undefined
```

Comment: What are you planning to use `JSON` or `JSONP`?

Comment: Is this a POST or a GET? Might be good to define that in your ajax call.

Comment: I don't have any data I need to post, so it's a GET. After adding it it still won't work. I just want to get data from another source (just another port at this moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to return

```
$_GET["callback"] . "('[\"a\":\"b\"]')"
```

and not just the JSON, because with JSONP jQuery expects to get back executable script code.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? `

Comment: see latest edit ... the ? was a placeholder for the actual callback function name that will be added by jQuery (something like jQuery1830690531364994632_1355864465030)

Comment: and it must be served with `Content-type: text/javascript` instead of `application/json`

Comment: my server is not written in PHP but the solution does indeed work, thanks!